# What is the difference, if any, between LONG and FAR jumps in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm looking at some practice code for assembly, and the assignment is basically to replace one jump point with another.

The original jmp is a SHORT jmp, and the end point I need to approach cannot be reached with this instruction.

I have three options now, I either remove 'SHORT', I insert 'LONG' or I insert 'FAR'.

If there's documentation anywhere that indicates the differences between them, I haven't found it yet.  Can anyone be of assistance here?

Comment: FYI, `long` is unusual terminology.  In most assemblers, the encoding overrides are `short` (rel8) or `near` (rel16 or rel32 depending on mode).  According to the answers here, `long` is the same rel16 / rel32 override that you get with NASM `jmp near foo`. See also  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp for the available forms in machine code.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm assuming your question pertains to the x86 architecture; you haven't specified in your question.

A `SHORT` jump is a jump to a particular offset from the current instruction pointer address. A `NEAR` jump can use a larger offset value, and so can jump further away from the current instruction pointer address. Both of these jump types are usually *relative* - that is, the operand is an offset from the current instruction pointer (though in assembly source, you normally provide the target label - the assembler or linker then computes the offset). **Neither of them jump to a different code segment**.

A `FAR` jump **specifies both a segment and offset**, which are both *absolute* in the sense that they specify the required code segment and instruction pointer, rather than an offset relative to the current code segment / instruction pointer.

A "long" jump is usually another name for a `FAR` jump (eg the AT&T syntax uses `ljmp` as an equivalent to `jmp far`), but your question implies use of an assembler where it equates to a `NEAR` jump.

To summarise, there are three types of direct jump: *short* and *near*, which are both jumps capable of jumping different relative distances with the same code segment, and *far* (or *long*), which can jump to any absolute address (segment and offset).

(Note that it is also possible to perform an *indirect absolute* jump, where you specify an operand that holds the absolute address that you wish to jump to. In this case the jump can either be near or far - i.e. it can include or not include the required code segment).

If you don't specify the jump 'distance', it is up to the assembler whether you get a short, near or far jump. Most modern assemblers are "two-pass" and will use a short jump if possible, or a near or far jump otherwise - the latter only if required.

See [wikipedia's entry on x86 memory segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) if you need help with understanding what I mean by 'segment'.

See [this description of the x86 JMP instruction](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html) for full details of the possible JMP instruction addressing modes.

Comment: Completely forgot to select an answer on this question.  D'oh.  Thank you for the explanation, it's been helpful!

Answer (score 7):

A `SHORT` jump:

- If it is a forward jump, the encoding uses a relative offset value from 00h (+0) to 7Fh (+127) which enables program execution to jump to another instruction with a maximum of 127 bytes in-between them.
- If it is a backward jump, the encoding uses a relative offset value from 80h (-128) to FFh (-1) which enables program execution to jump to another instruction with a maximum of 125 bytes in-between them.

A `LONG` jump, can use a larger offset.

A `FAR` jump, jumps to another code segment.

Comment: TL:DR a short jump is a rel8 signed 8-bit displacement added to EIP/RIP.

Answer (score 3):

TL:DR: `short` vs. `long`/`near` just forces the instruction length choice.
`far` is a totally different beast.

- `jmp short foo` is `jmp rel8`.
- `jmp long foo` or `jmp near foo` is `jmp rel16/rel32` (depending on mode)
- `jmp far [rdi]` is a jmp / call to a new CS:[ER]IP.  You rarely want this.

See Intel's manual (or an HTML scrape if you're familiar with the notation used) for the available machine-code forms of [`jmp`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp) / [`call`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call), [`jcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc) (conditionals like `jge`), and [`loop`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/loop:loopcc) (which is similar in encoding to a `jcc short`).

---

##### x86 has two major families of jumps/calls, with some variety within each:

- **Far** to a new CS:IP (or CS:EIP / CS:RIP depending on mode).
  Almost never used in normal 32 or 64-bit code (e.g. WOW64 32-bit system DLLs that call into 64-bit code that uses the `syscall` instruction), and only in 16-bit code if you can't fit your program into 64K, or in MBR bootloaders to set a known CS in real mode, or switch to 32-bit.

  Direct (except in 64-bit mode) or memory-indirect, but always absolute.  Interestingly, x86's only absolute direct jump.
  No conditional far jumps, only `jmp` or `call` / `retf`
  Syntax details depend on the assembler, but often something like `jmp 0x10:foo` or `jmp far [eax]` work in NASM, the latter loading 6 bytes from [DS:EAX] into CS:EIP if run in 32-bit mode.
- **Near** is a normal jump not changing CS, just setting a new IP/EIP/RIP.  The following forms are available:

  - *Indirect* (using absolute targets, e.g. function pointers or jump tables) like
    `jmp ax` or `jmp qword [rsi]`, or the same with `call`.  (Not conditional indirect `jcc`).  short or not isn't meaningful because the machine code for the instruction only encodes the place to find a new [ER]IP, not directly how to reach it.  `ax` vs. `eax` is  a matter of operand-size, or `[esi]` vs. `[rsi]` is a matter of address-size.  And `[rsi+0x1230]` is a matter of the disp8 / disp32 used as part of the addressing mode.
  - *Direct* using relative displacements (encoded into the machine code of the instruction) that get added to IP/EIP/RIP.  So they're relative to the end of the instruction<sup>1</sup>.  **This is what you get from a normal `jmp foo` or `jle .else`, with the assembler normally picking a length for you.**

    - **`short` means using an 8-bit (1-byte) relative displacement, aka a `rel8`**.
      Available for `jcc rel8` and `jmp rel8` (and `loop`), not `call`
    - non-short, using a `rel16` (16-bit mode<sup>2</sup>) or `rel32` (other modes).  So a 2-byte or 4-byte relative displacement.
      **You can force this encoding with `near` or `long` in the asm source.**
      Available for `jmp rel16/32` and `call rel16/32`, and on 386 and later `jcc rel16/32`.  If assembling with instructions restricted to 286 or earlier, an assembler will complain if the distance to the target label is outside the [-128, +127] range of a rel8, or use a fallback like a `jnle` over a `jmp`.
    - There is no near absolute direct.  For that use `mov eax, 0x123456` / `jmp eax` (near register-indirect) if you can't guarantee (or easily get the toolchain to calculate at link time) the distance between this code and the absolute target.

---

**Footnote 1:**    For example `EB 00` is a slow NOP using a short `jmp`.
Or `E8 00 00 00 00` / `5B` is a `call next` (or `call $+5`) / `next: pop ebx` like you might use to read EIP without actually going anywhere in 32-bit mode where RIP-relative LEA isn't available)

**Footnote 2:**:    Technically you *can* use `jmp rel16` in 32-bit mode, but it will truncate EIP to 16-bit.  (And the encoding uses a `66h` operand-size prefix so it's only 1 byte shorter than a `jmp rel32`)

In 16 and 32-bit mode, `jmp rel16/rel32` can reach any other IP/EIP value, but in 64-bit mode the +-2GiB range is only a small fraction of the virtual address space.  Still, it's normal for code for a single executable to assume that it fits in 2GiB so any code can reach any other code *in the same library or main executable* with a relative near jump/call.  A "large" code model would require `mov reg, imm64` / `jmp reg` or something inefficient like that.  Or even worse to make it position-independent.

---

**LONG is unusual terminology**. In most assemblers, the encoding overrides are `short` (rel8) or `near` (rel16 or rel32 depending on mode) to force the length (and thus how far you can jump) for near jumps (`cs` unchanged, just adding an offset to IP/EIP/RIP)

According to the other answers here, in assemblers where `long` is a thing, it's the same rel16 or rel32 override that you get with NASM `jmp near foo`.

NASM listing (`nasm -felf32 foo.asm  -l/dev/stdout`)

```
     1                                  foo:
     2 00000000 E9FBFFFFFF              jmp  near foo
     3 00000005 EBF9                    jmp  foo           ; optimizes to short by default
     4 00000007 EBF7                    jmp short foo
```

NASM does multi-pass optimization to find the shortest encoding it can use for each branch.  This is usually optimal, but see [Why is the "start small" algorithm for branch displacement not optimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911142/why-is-the-start-small-algorithm-for-branch-displacement-not-optimal) for corner cases where manually forcing one branch's encoding could allow smaller code.

If the branch target is in another file so NASM doesn't know at assemble time how far away it'll be, it assumes `near` (non-short).  You could force that if you know the files you'll be linking together are small (or the code is in a special section).

Or if you want to leave a full `rel32` for something else to modify this machine code and write a new offset, that would be a use-case for `near`.  For example, the PLT used in dynamic linking on Linux used to work that way (I think), rewriting an offset in a `jmp rel32` instead of doing an indirect jmp with a GOT entry.

Historically, some assemblers are not as smart as NASM, and always needed manual hinting if you wanted the short encoding for jumps.  Especially for forward jumps, to a label the assembler hasn't seen yet. (If you're working with 16-bit code using old tools from that era, you may run into this.)   Even NASM used to default to optimization disabled in old versions, which would make it choose the long encoding.

Also, `jcc near` is only supported on 386 and later, so you may need to be explicit if you want your assembler to actually emit that.

Comment: Far superior answer when compared to the others in this thread

Comment: @AndriySultanov: Thanks, I'm glad it was worth the effort to write it 7 years after the other two.  I was probably looking for a canonical answer to link as a duplicate about short vs. near vs. far jumps and hadn't found one.